# Unwrapping a value using SwiftJSON results in an error on iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, string, swifty-json

I have an external api providing the data, which I need to decode and assign to a label in my view.

I am using the following in a collectionView so don't mind the `collectionView.tag` and `indexPath.row`

I am also using `SwiftyJson` to parse json values `.string` providing and optional value

```
let value = servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag]["subcategories"][indexPath.row]["name"].string
```

Now when I try to assign this value to a label

```
cell.serviceName.text = value
```

I get an error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
```

I had to put the value inside something like this when assigning:

```
`"\(value)"`
```

This works fine but it has the `Optional` text around the values.

I also tried to:

- unwrap the value `cell.serviceName.text = value!` gives the same error
- used `.stringValue` instead of `.string` which gives the non-optional value gives the same error
  -used `.rawString` instead of `.string` gives the same error
- tried unwrapping it this way

```
if let value = servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag] 
   ["subcategories"][indexPath.row]["name"].string {
        cell.serviceName.text = value
}
```

same error

- and tried giving it a default value `cell.serviceName.text = value ?? "default"` same error

i just tried to check all the response on by one like this:

```
if servicesResponse["data"] != JSON.null{
            if servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag] != JSON.null{
                if servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag]["subcategories"] != JSON.null{
                    if servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag]["subcategories"][indexPath.row] != JSON.null{
                        if servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag]["subcategories"][indexPath.row]["name"] != JSON.null{
                            print("ALL PASS=========================")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and all of the pass

I'd like to know if there is a way to remove the text `Optional` while the value is still optional or if anyone knows what this error means and why it happens.

The error only occurs on `iOS13`. works fine on earlier versions

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you could post the json as well, perhaps a simplified version of it. that could help.

Comment: well i thought theres no problem with the data since it works on ios12 and below and the correct data is displayed with the optional around it

Comment: Drop `SwiftyJSON` and parse the JSON into a reasonable model with `Decodable`

Answer (score 1):

The `value` variable is an Optional string, that's why it shows the `Optional()` when you print it.

To unwrap the optional you can do something like this:

```
if let unwrappedValue = value {
    cell.serviceName.text = unwrappedValue
}
```

Or if you prefer, you can do it in one line with the nil coalescing operator:

```
cell.serviceName.text = value ?? "Text in case of nil"
```

Comment: i know why it giving me the `Optional()` when i unwrap it, it throws the error,check the question again

Comment: When you option click the `value` variable what type do you see?

Comment: i see an optional `String` type

Answer (score 0):

It's because your value is an optional.

Try through this way

```
if let value = servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag]["subcategories"][indexPath.row]["name"] {
    cell.serviceName.text = value.stringValue
}
```

Comment: i know but unwrapping it is whats causing the error, i just tried your code and same error.

Comment: Can you try my new answer

Comment: this `servicesResponse["data"][collectionView.tag]["subcategories"][indexPath.row]["name"]` doesnt return an optional value i dont think i can use optional binding method

Answer (score 0):

The error shows a string being initialized with a nil argument so there something not quite right with the json data, or the way it's being decoded.

Why don't you do the unwrapping in stages, rather than a one liner. When you're dealing with an unknown error it is always better to breakdown the process into small chunks and then examine each individually. When you discover where your problem is, you can always go back to the one liner, applying what you've learned.

This is what I came up with (and tested) to illustrate a one way to debug in a gradual JSON decoding process.

Given a raw json string:

```
let rawString = """
{"statusCode":200,"message":"Success","data":[{"_id":"someid","isActive":true,"subcategories":[{"_id":"id","photo":"image/url/30973327066756228460065.png","services":[{"_id":"id","properties":[{"_id":"id","isMultiSelect":false,"responses":["1","2","3","4","5"],"other_name":"የክፍሎች ቁጥር","name":"Number of rooms"}],"other_name":"ጽዳት","name":"Cleaning"}],"other_name":"ጽዳት","name":"Cleaning","other_subcategory_label":"ጽዳት","subcategory_label":"Cleaning"}],"name":"Home Cleaning","__v":0,"other_name":"የቤት ጽዳት"}]}
"""
```

We can gradually decode, validate and then unwrap the name value at the end.

```
let parsedJson = JSON.init(parseJSON: rawString)

let verifiedDataJson = parsedJson["data"]
guard verifiedDataJson != JSON.null else {
    return
}

let verifiedCollectionViewTagJson = verifiedDataJson[0]
guard verifiedCollectionViewTagJson != JSON.null else {
    return
}

let verifiedSubCategoriesJson = verifiedCollectionViewTagJson["subcategories"]
guard verifiedSubCategoriesJson != JSON.null else {
    return
}

let verifiedIndexPathRowJson = verifiedSubCategoriesJson[0]
guard verifiedIndexPathRowJson != JSON.null else {
    return
}

guard let unwrappedNameValue = verifiedIndexPathRowJson["name"].string as String? else {
    return
}
```

Comment: ya you are right but theres no null value on it i have tried it like this before it passes all the conditions and fails at the same point always

Comment: is there a way i can just ignore the `Oprional` text and print only the value without unwrapping

Comment: The error shows a string being initialized with a nil argument so there something not quite right with the json data. hence the call for validation.

Comment: i tried like you suggested and all conditions pass i edited my question with your suggestion check it let me know if i should change anything @EarlGrey

Comment: I'll help you more if you post the json. You can remove all sensitive values, just replace them with "Redacted" or something like that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working code example.